# Does the Oracle database username exist for each Linux account?

Tags: linux, oracle, sqlplus

Does the Oracle database username exist for each Linux account?

The former employee left the company and can not find the details at this time.

I can log in to the Linux root account and run a DB query through sqlplus.
If I log in as the Linux oracle account, I can not log in with the username that was logged in as the root account.

I do not know which setting I made.

I have a few questions,

1. As the title suggests, does the Oracle database username exist for every Linux account?
   I'm wondering if there is a database username that can only be logged in to the Linux root account.
2. I would like you to give me a general idea of what configuration should be changed to run as the root account in the Linux oracle account.

Comment: 1) Doubtful/No.  As the oracle database service could be installed on a linux box with 100's of accounts already on it.  and the two are distinct in their functions. 2) Since the two are not linked you can't do this.  There should be an oracle admin account which is the "Root" of the service.  be VERY careful when using the account as just like root you have God level privileges to the application.  Just like Linux you shouldn't operate as Root/SA except to manage very specific situations and in so doing it should be to grant privileges to an account so you can do the change in that account.

Comment: If you are the Oracle root (i.e. sysdba as / or similar - itś been a while!) you can change **anybody's** password!

Comment: @Vérace My question is not about "Oracle DB root's work" like sysdba. It's about 'is there difference Oracle DB login work according to linux account?'. But thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the Oracle database username exist for every Linux account?

No - Operating System accounts and Oracle database accounts are unrelated.

Comment: Not actually true. You can configure Oracle to externally authenticate

Answer (score 0):

May, but only if configured like so.

In "default" configurations, linux username only acts as a owner of the software and it has nothing to do with database users/schemas.

However you can configure external authentification to OS level or even LDAP level. Depending on the configuration He/She did, you can have one db user/schema correlated with one OS user, all of them, some of them, none of them, etc..

For instance: Did you check you're connecting to the same database? This is my first bet, since external authentification is not very common (but not very environments are common,. so,. who knows)

I highly recommend to leave this job to an experienced oracle dba. Don't mess with your data.

Comment: I connected to same database through sqlplus, just change linux user account.

Comment: How do you know it? How did you check it? I again say my bet is you're connecting to different databases. There are many different connection methods and configurations, and the same connection procedure can result in very different behaviors depending on your configuration. This problem only have one solution: Hire a new oracle dba.

Answer (score -2):

I think it will depend on how it is organized it. Try contacting the former person in charge.